# How can I have a hashmap of form params coming in curl request in my jersey servlet?

Tags: java, curl, hashmap, jersey, jax-rs

I am making a curl request like:

```
curl -i -X POST -d "debit_user_id=/customer/mobile_number:917827448775&recipient_id=/customer/mobile_number:9988776655/recipients/mobile_number:917526337452&pintwin=1234&amount=5000&currency=INR&customer_id=/customer/mobile_number:9988776655&agent_id=/agents/mobile_number:919987536699" http://localhost:8080/switch/apikongcall.do/transactions
```

And I am getting these parameters in my jersey servlet like:

```
@POST
//@Path("/transactions")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void initiatePostTransaction(@FormParam("debit_user_id") String debit_user_id,
        @FormParam("recipient_id") String recipient_id,
        @FormParam("pintwin") String pintwin,
        @FormParam("amount") String amount,
        @FormParam("currency") String currency,
        @FormParam("customer_id") String customer_id,
        @FormParam("agent_id") String agent_id) {
```

My question is there any way I can create a hashmap for these parameters so I dont need to extract these with their names individually. I jest need the hashmap so even if somebody adds a new parameter later, I don't need to change anything. Is there a way to remove this dependency in jersey.?

Comment: Replace all the @FormParams with a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` should work.

Comment: @peeskillet You should just make that an answer.